# AngularJS. How to update headers that was initialized in app.run dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I want to add custom header for every request in my Angular application.
Currently I do this next way:

```
app.run(['list of dependencies', function(dependencies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['custom_header'] = $cookies.get('custom_cookie');
}]);
```

All works OK until my custom cookie has no changes. But when cookie is changed, `$http` sends old cookie that was initialized in `app.run`. So for update headers I need to reload the page.

**What I need to add for update header dynamically?** Of course, I can update header directly, for example, in controller, but it seems I repeating myself this way. And also this approach making code unclear and complicated.

I want have all headers configuration in one site.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Put all the code that deals with that cookie in a service. Call a service method from the run() block, that initializes the header from the cookie. Make sure that every time the cookie is modified/deleted inside the service, the header is modified as well.

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, you can also store functions in the headers map: `$http.defaults.headers.common['custom_header'] = function() { return $cookies.get('custom_cookie'); };`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for comments! Your second comment is what I need. You can post it as answer and I will accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the documentation, you can store functions in the headers map:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['custom_header'] = function() { 
    return $cookies.get('custom_cookie'); 
};
```

That way, every time a request is sent, Angular will get the latest cookie value from the function, and if not null, will set the header.